# You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page Error Although i have'nt include

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have read all tutorials about this error. But i couldn't solve my problem. I  want to show map according to the my longitude and latitude using Google apis. 
i added maps api to use Google map like as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

After this library is added in _Layout.cshtml, i got error like as below:

```
You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

This error is occurred even without adding any code about Google maps in map.cshtml file. So that i think this error is not relevant is Google map code. Google maps code in map.cshtml file is like as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitializeMap();
    });

    function InitializeMap() {
        var data = {
            Latitude: '@Model.Latitude',
            Longitude: '@Model.Longitude'
        };
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: latlong,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            fullscreenControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), myOptions);
    } 
</script>
```

the div tag which will show Google map is like as below:

```
<div id="Map" style="width: 750px; height: 500px"></div>
```

I searched 'googleapis' word in all current project but i can't find another one.The error is below:
[image]

Comment: check the developer tools console/network and inspect tabs when loading the page - you should be able to see where and how this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error recently. I wanted to show map according to longitude and latitude. The map is showed when serach button is clicked. When search button is clicked and than the coordinates is sent to the controller action method. And then map is showed the same page. Because I call controller action with ajax in javascript. So that two view page are on the same view. Every time i got this error. My search button which is in index.html is below:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-warning" style="height:35px;width:120px">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <translate>Search</translate>
</button>
```

My ajax call which is in index.html is like as below:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {      
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "ControllerName")',
                data: { Name: $('#Name').val() },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mapSupriseForm").html(data);
                }
            });
    });
```

Map is showed in 'mapSupriseForm' suprise form in index.html. it is below:

```
<div id="mapSupriseForm"></div>
```

Google map codes were in search.cshtml. Search.cshtml is showed in index.cshtml. Namely index.cshtml and search.cshtml is the same place. I added google maps api library to the _Layout.cshtml. Search.cshtml and index.cshtml use _Layout.cshtml as loyout. So that google maps api is added multiple times and than error is thrown by browser. Search.cshtml is in index.cshtml so search.cshtml shouldn't add _Layout.cshtml. search.cshtml already use _Layout.cshtml because of index.cshtml. Because of all these reasons i disable layout from search.cshtml like as below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "";
}
```

In this way the google maps api library is added once. And the error is solved.    I hope this experience will help you for solving your problem.